# Incluir todas las entradas de una tabla en una relación

Tags: sql, postgresql

Verán, tengo estas 3 tablas que gestionan un concesionario:

```
create table coche(
  id serial primary key,
  nombre varchar,
  fabricante varchar,
  anno_fabricacion integer,
  precio integer,
  plazas integer
);

create table cliente(
  id serial primary key,
  nombre varchar,
  dni integer,
  fecha_registro date
);

create table compra(
  id serial primary key,
  coche integer references coche(id) on delete cascade,
  cliente integer references cliente(id) on delete cascade,
  fecha date
);
```

Con estas tablas, quiero mostrar una listas con cuanto dinero se ha gastado cada cliente comprando.
Para eso, tengo esta petición:

```
SELECT cliente.nombre as nombre, sum(precio) as gastado FROM compra, coche, cliente WHERE coche.id=coche AND cliente=cliente.id GROUP BY cliente.id ORDER BY cliente.id;
```

Esto me devuelve el nombre de cada cliente y cuanto se ha gastado cada uno, pero hay un problema: Si un cliente aún no ha comprado ningún coche, no aparecerá. Lo que quiero es que si un cliente no ha comprado coche, que aparezca en la tabla con su valor de "gastado" a 0.
Por lo que veo debería usar "GROUP BY ALL", pero no me funciona. ¿Como se hace en postgresql?

Actualizo: Investigando como podía arreglarlo encontré este modo:

```
select cliente.nombre, sum(precio) from compra join coche on coche.id=coche right join cliente on cliente.id=cliente group by cliente.id;
```

Con esto, ya se muestra también los clientes que no han comprando ningún coche, pero hay un detalle que no me termina de convencer:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¡Los clientes que no han comprado coches tienen la variable sum(precio) como valor nulo!
Yo lo que quiero es que en caso de ser nulo, se muestre de valor un 0.

Comment: Chale, tú mismo ya te lo tienes casi listo. Prueba esto: select cliente.nombre, ISNULL(sum(precio), 0 ) from compra join coche on coche.id=coche right join cliente on cliente.id=cliente group by cliente.id;

Comment: Me sale este mensaje de error: HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add 
explicit type casts.
Vamos, parece que postgresql no le agrada el ISNULL.

Comment: Puede que lo haya puesto al revés, el ISNULL dentro y SUM fuera... sino prueba con la función CASE. Por cierto, yo no he usado PostgreSQL, he usado otros motores, pero son todos casi iguales.

Answer (score 1):

Vale, ya he encontrado una solución:

```
select cliente.nombre, coalesce(sum(precio), 0 ) from compra join coche on coche.id=coche right join cliente on cliente.id=cliente group by cliente.id;
```

Esto dará el siguiente resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esto los clientes que aún no hayan comprado coche aparecerán con un valor de gasto en 0.